# How can I compile object code for the wrong system and cross compiling question?

Tags: macos, cross-compiling

Reference [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145728/how-do-i-compile-a-32-bit-apache-module-for-a-64-bit-platform) about compiling.  I don't understand how my program for Mac can use the right -arch, compile with those -arch flags, the -arch flags be for the system I am on (a ppc64 g5), and still produce the wrong object code.

Also, if I used a cross compiler and was on Linux, produced 10.5 code for mac, how would this be any different than what I described above?

Background is that I have tried to compile various apache modules.  They compile with the -arch ppc, ppc64, etc.  I get no errors and I get my mod_whatever.so.  But, apache will always complain that some symbol isn't found.  Apparently, it has to do with what the compiler produces, even though the file type says it is for ppc, ppc64, i386, x_64 (universal binary) and seems to match all the other .so mods I have.

I guess I don't understand how it could compile for my system with no problem and then say my system can't use it.  Maybe I do not understand what a compiler is actually giving me.

EDIT:  All error messages and the complete process can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145728/how-do-i-compile-a-32-bit-apache-module-for-a-64-bit-platform).

Thank you.

Comment: You need to be more specific.  Exactly what error messages are you seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the other thread and elsewhere and without a G5 or OSX Server installation, I can only make a few comments and suggestions but perhaps they will help.

1. It's generally not a good idea to be modifying the o/s vendor's installed software.  Installing a new Apache module is less problematic than, say, overwriting an existing library but you're still at the mercy of the vendor in that a Software Update could delete your modifications and, beyond that you have to figure out how the vendor's version was built in the first place.  A common practice in the OS X world is to avoid this by making a completely separate installation of an open source product, like Apache, using, for instance, [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=category&substr=www). That has its cons, too: to achieve a high-level of independence, MacPorts will often download and build a lot of dependent packages for things which are already in OS X but there's no harm in that other than some extra build cycles and disk space.
2. That said, it should be possible to build and install apache modules to supplement those supplied by Apple.  Apple does publish the changes it makes to open source products [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/); you can drill down in the various versions there to find the apache directory which contains the source, Makefile and applied patches.  That might be of help.
3. Make sure that the mod_*.so you build are truly 64-bit and don't depend on any non-64 bit libraries.  Use `otool -L mod_*.so` to see the dynamic libraries that each references and then use `file` on those libraries to ensure they all have ppc64 variants.
4. Make sure you are using up-to-date developer tools (Xcode 3.1.3 is current).
5. While the developer tool chain uses many open source components, Apple has enhanced many of them and there are big differences in OS X's ABIs, universal binary support, dynamic libraries, etc.  The bottom line is that cross-compilation of OS X-targeted object code on Linux (or any other non-OS X platform) is neither supported nor practical.